# android write text on image library

Tags: android, graphics, fonts

are there any libraries to easily write text in different places of image without performing a lot of math? I need to write coordinates on photo in left-top corner. Only way I see now is to use canvas, but it needs to calculate coordinates, font size and other things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
Bitmap bitmap = ... // Load your bitmap here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(10); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text here", x, y, paint);
```

[This](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/08/draw-text-on-bitmap-using-canvasdrawtext.html) will help you

Comment: I wrote about this way in my post,  this requires computations of font, coordinates and so on. I was asking about libraries which can help make this easier

Comment: got any solution. any libraries?